# Django; cannot load static files

Tags: python, django

I've been working on Django and my static files cannot loaded. 
My project structure is like this

```
blog/
|___apps/
|     |__static/
|     |     |__css/
|     |     |__js/
|     |
|     |__templates/
|     |     |__base.html
|     |     |__feeds/
|     |
|     |__feeds/
|
|___blog/
       settings.py
```

my `settings.py` is like this

```
APPS_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(APPS_DIR, 'static'),
   )
```

The weird thing is only for `index.html`, static files can be loaded even though html files are inside `templates/feeds/`.

there might be fault in my `urls.py` because the error says like

> Not Found: /feeds/static/css/styles.css

seems like Django tries to find static files inside `static/feeds/`.

`urls.py` is like this

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),

path('feeds/', include([
    path('list', views.list_entry, name='list_entry'),
```

I don't want to create app name folder inside `static` if possible. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can I see list_entry view?

Comment: Show us how are you loading static files? Is it like `/static/` or `static/` or `{%static "path" %}`? `static/` is a wrong way to load static files, from the `url` I can say you are using that approach only.

Comment: Actually it works just now. I used loading static files like `static` and changed it to {% static path %} and it does work.

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

Try importing these in the project url and then add the following :

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name='index')
  ....
  ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: actually I already added `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`. Should I change this?

Comment: its worked for media. you must add static url for static files as Nikhil said